# What is the heat equation when the heat capacity changes?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, differential-equations

The typical heat equation is:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= \frac{\beta}{2} \frac{\partial ^2 T}{\partial x^2}$$

but this only works in when the heat capacity $\alpha$ is constant across the substance. If the heat capacity is different, temperatures don't average out, rather:

$$T_f = \frac{\alpha_1 T_{i_1}+\alpha_2 T_{i_2}}{\alpha_1+\alpha_2} $$

for equal masses.

I tried generalizing the heat equation as follows:

$$\frac{\partial T_2}{\partial t}=\beta (\frac{\alpha_1T_1+\alpha_3T_3}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_3}-T_2)$$
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= \beta\frac{1}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_3}(\alpha_3 \Delta T_3-\alpha_1 \Delta T_1)$$

but I don't know how to make this a continuum. My intuition says that it is:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= \beta\frac{1}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_3}\Delta(\alpha \Delta T)$$

$$\\\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \beta \frac{1}{2\alpha(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\alpha(x) \frac{\partial T}{\partial x})$$

Which reduces to the original heat equation when the heat capacity is constant across the substance.

Is my intuition right?

Comment: Please define your variables. Different fields use different symbols, and it’s especially confusing when you refer to a symbol that doesn’t even appear in the preceding equation. For example, is $\beta$ is intended to be twice the thermal diffusivity, which is inversely proportional to the specific heat capacity $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

The heat equation comes from the basic statement"

"Change in energy in a differential volume" = "Sum of the energy transfers into or out of the volume"

Which mathematically looks like:

$$\frac{dE}{dt}= \nabla Q
$$

Using the fact that $dE=mc \,dT$ and the Fourier heat conduction law $Q=-k\nabla T$, we can write:

$$\frac{d(mcT)}{dt}= -\nabla (k\nabla T) $$

If $k$ is constant with temperature, we can factor that out, and the right side becomes $-k\nabla^2 T$.  If in addition, $m=\rho V$ and $\rho$ and $c$ are constant, you can factor those out and combine the properties into thermal diffusivity $\alpha =k/(\rho c)$ and get the equation you are familiar with.

If any of those assumptions like constant heat capacity $c$ are not applicable, you have to use the unsimplified form of the equation, likely solving it numerically.